# Drupal.settings.basePath is not giving the base_url in js

Tags: 6, javascript, uri

When I alerted the `Drupal.settings.basePath` it's just giving me a `/`. I have a full `$base_url` in settings.php. which I'm expecting to see instead of `/`.

How can I get the correct value of the base URL in javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass it manually like this.

```
global $base_url;
drupal_add_js(array('baseUrl' => $base_url), 'setting');
```

Then call like this `Drupal.settings.baseUrl`.

`Drupal.settings.basePath` value is coming from `base_path()` api. See this documentation about [base_path](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/base_path/6).

Comment: why is it necessary to use global $base_url; before passing the variable ?

Comment: Because it is not available inside a hook by default

Comment: But i can use $base_url as a variable  in the same file though

Comment: it really works for me